# Add more action after then condition in haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement

I want to after reaching the first contain, doing multiple functions like func1 then finc2 then fun3 is there any way to do that in haskell? I am not sure using >>?

```
myexe [] = []
myexe (x:xs) 
             | x < head xs             = myexe xs , func1, func2 , func3
             | otherwise               = x
```

Comment: Executing multiple functions in order has no real meaning in Haskell unless they're monadic functions.  Are you wanting to do monadic operations, or are you wanting to do extra processing with a return value?  Remember, pure functions _can't_ modify anything, only return a value.  Haskell won't even compute the function unless the value is needed

Comment: This sounds to me like an XY problem. You have a problem X you want to solve, and an idea Y about how to solve it, and you're asking about your idea instead of the problem. I encourage you to take a step back and think about how to ask a good question about X instead -- you'll get better advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want several functions, you always could write

```
result = f3 (f2 (f1 x))
```

or same, using function application

```
result = f3 $ f2 $ f1 x
```

or same, using functional composition

```
result = f3 . f2 . f1 $ x
```

You could find more details here: [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but could it be "let":

```
| x < head xs             = let 
                              a = myexe xs
                              b = func1 a
                              c = func2 b
                  in func3 c
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the types for func1 2 and 3?

You can do func1 . func2 . func3 . myexe xs If they are all [a]-> [a]

Also beware :

1. `x < head xs`    may do `head []` , generating an exeption
2. `= x`  a mistake if x is not a list of the right type.